# Issues adding child to GridLayout dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am making a puzzle game. I am trying to make a `GridLayout` dynamically of size 4x4. I am adding `LinearLayout` as the child and then an `ImageView` inside the `LinearLayout` of the GridLayout through code. Layout is coming perfectly fine. But when I drop an ImageView in any of the grid the image is taking complete height and width of the GridLayout. But it should only take the size of the grid in which it is dropped.

***[Github link of the project.](https://github.com/SAGARSURI/DragDropDemo)***

Here is my code:

```
    public class PuzzleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.puzzle_layout);

        findViewById(R.id.a0).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.b0).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.c0).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.d0).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.e0).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        GridLayout layout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
        layout.setRowCount(4);
        layout.setColumnCount(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            GridLayout.Spec rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(i, 1,1);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                GridLayout.Spec colSpec = GridLayout.spec(j, 1,1);
                LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0,0));
                linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                linearLayout.setId(R.id.row + i + R.id.col + j);
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
                linearLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.layout_background));
                linearLayout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                linearLayout.addView(imageView);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams myGLP = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
                myGLP.rowSpec = rowSpec;
                myGLP.columnSpec = colSpec;
                layout.addView(linearLayout, myGLP);
            }
        }
    }

    private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                        view);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    view.startDragAndDrop(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                } else {
                    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                }
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

        private View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("Image name", view.getContentDescription() + "");
                ImageView newImage = (ImageView) view;
                newImage.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) newImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), 90));
                //view.setRotation(view.getRotation()+90);
            }
        };

        private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int rotationAngleDegree) {

            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
            int h = bitmap.getHeight();

            int newW = w, newH = h;
            if (rotationAngleDegree == 90 || rotationAngleDegree == 270) {
                newW = h;
                newH = w;
            }
            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newW, newH, bitmap.getConfig());
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(rotatedBitmap);

            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, newW, newH);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            float px = rect.exactCenterX();
            float py = rect.exactCenterY();
            matrix.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth() / 2, -bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
            matrix.postRotate(rotationAngleDegree);
            matrix.postTranslate(px, py);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
            matrix.reset();

            return rotatedBitmap;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    // do nothing
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    /**
                     * Change background of the layout where item is entering
                     */
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ECECEC"));
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    /**
                     * Change background of the layout back to normal once item is moved out of it
                     */
                    v.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(PuzzleActivity.this, R.drawable.layout_background));
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;

                    // Added the following to copy the old view's bitmap to a new ImageView:
                    ImageView oldView = (ImageView) view;
                    ImageView newView = (ImageView) container.getChildAt(0);
                    newView.setId(oldView.getId());
                    newView.setContentDescription(oldView.getContentDescription());
                    newView.setOnClickListener(myListener);
                    newView.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) oldView.getDrawable()).getBitmap());

                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    View currentView = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    currentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    v.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(PuzzleActivity.this, R.drawable.layout_background));
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my `layout.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/kolamShapesLayout"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="70dp"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:rowCount="3">

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/kolamShapesLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:columnCount="5"
        app:rowCount="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/a0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/a0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/c0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/c0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/c0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/e0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/e0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/e0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/d0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/d0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/d0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/b0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/b0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is how the Layout is looking:**

[image]

**But when I drop an Image in the any of the grid its taking complete height and width of the `GridLayout`:**

[image]

If I am doing creating a static `GridLayout` in `layout.xml` its working fine. Problem comes when I am creating dynamic `GridLayout`.

**Here is my `layout.xml` which i used previously to create static `GridLayout` and it worked fine. But now I am trying dynamic creation of GridLayout through code which is giving me issues:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/kolamShapesLayout"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="70dp"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:rowCount="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row0col0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row0col1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row0col2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1col0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1col1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1col2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row2col0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row2col1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row2col2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/kolamShapesLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:columnCount="5"
        app:rowCount="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/a0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/a0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/c0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/c0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/c0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/e0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/e0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/e0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/d0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/d0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/d0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/b0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/b0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

***[Github link of the project.](https://github.com/SAGARSURI/DragDropDemo)***

Comment: Can you post a simple project at github demonstrating that behavior?

Comment: https://github.com/SAGARSURI/DragDropDemo Here is the project where I am facing issue. Please check `PuzzleActivity.java` and `puzzle_layout.xml` @azizbekian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at where you are adding the linear layout to the grid view in `onCreate()`. Early on you are setting the layout params as follows:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

Yet, later on, you are adding the linear layouts with a different set of layout params as follows:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams myGLP = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
myGLP.rowSpec = rowSpec;
myGLP.columnSpec = colSpec;
layout.addView(linearLayout, myGLP);
```

This will negate the earlier layout parameters. I suggest you change the code to the following:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams myGLP = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
myGLP.rowSpec = rowSpec;
myGLP.columnSpec = colSpec;
myGLP.width = 0;
myGLP.height = 0;
layout.addView(linearLayout, myGLP);
```

You can delete the earlier code.

Here is a video of the result:

[image]

Comment: It worked!! Awesome. Thanks a ton. Marked your answer green and you deserve the +50 points as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you, use google `flexbox-layout` instead of  `support GridLayout`. its much more flexible and also stable and easy to use.

See more about it in [github](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

**UPDATE:**

This is sample for static XML layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:id="@+id/flexLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="70dp"
        app:alignContent="stretch"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:flexDirection="row"
        app:flexWrap="wrap">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row0col0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_flexGrow="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row0col1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FFFF00"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_flexGrow="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row0col2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FF00FF"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_flexGrow="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1col0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_flexGrow="1"
            app:layout_wrapBefore="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1col1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#00FFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_flexGrow="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1col2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_flexGrow="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row2col0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_flexGrow="1"
            app:layout_wrapBefore="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row2col1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FFFF00"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_flexGrow="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row2col2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FF00FF"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_flexGrow="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want dynamically add children, see this sample:

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:id="@+id/flexLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="70dp"
        app:alignContent="stretch"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:flexDirection="row"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class PuzzleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.puzzle_dynamic);

        FlexboxLayout layout = (FlexboxLayout) findViewById(R.id.flexLayout);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));
                linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                //linearLayout.setId(R.id.row + i + R.id.col + j);
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
                linearLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.layout_background));
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                linearLayout.addView(imageView);

                FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams(FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                lp.setFlexGrow(1);

                if (j == 0)
                    lp.setWrapBefore(true);//notice to this!

                layout.addView(linearLayout, lp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For add `flexbox` to code project, put this line in your gradle dependency:

`compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0'`

Comment: can you show me the implementation using `Flexbox layout` ?

Comment: I dont think `Flexbox-layout` will solve my problem. I tried creating the same grid layout as above. But it seems more difficult.

Comment: @Hiren I put some samples.

Comment: I will try @ramineftekhari I have even added the github link of the project I am facing issue in. Please check the updated question if you want to.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with your implementation as well. The Image I am dragging and dropping in one of the `LinearLayout` inside `flexbox-layout`, the image is taking complete height and width of the `flexbox-layout` inturn hiding other `linearlayout`

Comment: Please check the github link which I added in the question. @ramineftekhari